# Heil PR-35 versus Electro Voice RE 50 N /DBL

Tags: microphone, dynamic

which one would you buy and why?

needed for voice recordings on street and inside

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try any of those, but I think that Electro Voice RE 50 N /DBL is better (specification, brand, reviews, etc) .